# Getting the error SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}' in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a dynamic html `td` as shown below:

```
var id = "testId";
var issueId = "testIssueId";

var sourceRow = ($(this).find("OBJECTID").text() === "") ? '<td></td>' : "<td><img src='contactImages/attachmentImage.png' onclick='issueAttachmentAttachmentLookUp('"+id+"','"+issueId+"')'> </img></td>" ;
```

I am getting the following error when I click on the above  `td`(In Firefox):

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'

The function is:

```
function issueAttachmentAttachmentLookUp(strIssueID, issueID1)
{
    var aryArgument = new Array();

    aryArgument[0] = m_stateData;
    aryArgument[1] = g_ContactSoapWebServiceURL;
    aryArgument[2] = g_PQContactTree;
    aryArgument[3] = strIssueID;
    aryArgument[4] = m_PQClientConfig;
    aryArgument[5] = g_BAList;
    aryArgument[6] = g_references;
    aryArgument[7] = ResponseNode;
    aryArgument[8] = issueCurrentBA;
    aryArgument[9] = issueID1;

    ModalHelper.showModalDialog(
        'PQCaseAttachment.htm',
        'Issue Attachments',
        890,
        700,
        aryArgument,
        function(refreshWindow)
        {
            if(refreshWindow){
                refresh();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

I am suspecting that something is wrong with the onclick event syntax, but couldn't identify the problem.

Anybody has any clue?

Comment: Your `var issueId` does not get closing `"` and contains some additional `)` at the end

Comment: `var issueId = "testIssueId)` should be `var issueId = "testIssueId)"` => you're missing a double quote

Comment: That's typo error. Now I have corrected the question

Comment: @treyBake , Please take a look at the question now.

Comment: your error: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'` does it give a line number? not seeing any use of `}` in your question?

Comment: @ treyBake, The line number is shown as '2' which doesn't make sense at all. No error is thrown if I remove the `onclick`

Comment: @Ashok.N can we see this function code: `issueAttachmentAttachmentLookUp`

Comment: @ treyBake, Added the function to the question now

Comment: what are all those variable values? They're not defined anywhere in the function?

Comment: They are defined in the file. I cannot share entire file here.

Comment: @Ashok.N but they exist outside of the function .. meaning they're all undefined ...

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error. Your second line should be:

```
var issueId = "testIssueId";
```

Comment: typo issues shouldn't be answered - just VTC

Answer (score 0):

You have too many single quotes. Your `onclick` will look like this:

```
onclick='issueAttachmentAttachmentLookUp('id','issueId')'
        ^                                ^  ^ ^       ^ ^
```

See how there are extra single quotes? Replace these with `\"` inside of the onclick:

```
onclick=\"issueAttachmentAttachmentLookUp('"+id+"','"+issueId+"')\"
```

Comment: He says, "I am suspecting that something is wrong with the `onclick` event syntax, but couldn't identify the problem."

Comment: but that's not the issue.. read the question and error message given, there is no `}` anywhere ...